# Can't connect using PHP sqlsrv_connect - server not found

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using PHP 7.0.15, running IIS locally, and I'm trying to connect to our main SQL Server box.  I have successfully loaded the sqlsrv extension, tested with

```
echo "Did sqlsrv load? " . (extension_loaded('sqlsrv') ? "YES" : "NO");
```

which returns YES.  The SQL instance on the box I'm connecting to is hdnysql1\hdnysql1, verified with select @@serverName. I've checked that I can connect running SQL Server Management Studio using Windows authentication, and I'm trying to use Windows authentication in the code:

```
$servername = "hdnysql1\hdnysql1";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"MCDB_Test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

This returns a connection failure; sqlsrv_errors returns an array including

```
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server
Login timeout expired
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/) and verified that remote connections are allowed to the server.  The TCP port setting in SQL Server Configuration Manager was blank; I set it to 1433 on IP2, restarted services, and things appear to be working; SSRS had to be restarted too but that's working OK.  I telnetted to the server on port 1433 to be sure it was open and disabled my firewall, and still no luck -- still getting the same message.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the sql server service running?

Comment: Yes, checked on the services at the server, and also verified by refreshing an SSRS page that points to the server.

Comment: From the error message, it appears sqlsrv_connect is attempting to use named pipes, not TCP/IP. Did you verify the named pipes protocol is enabled in SQL Server configuration manager (or check into how to force sqlsrv_connect to *not* use named pipes)? Did you try using the IP address instead of `hdnysql1` as the server name? You say 1433 - but that is typically not the port used by a named instance. Are you sure this is a named instance and not a default instance? Are you sure the service is now running on 1433?

Comment: Named pipes were not enabled, but I've now enabled them (and restarted services) and that didn't fix it.  I tried the IP address as well as hdnysql1, both with and without the backslash and named instance.  In the config manager it shows a list of IPs and then IP All at the end; IP2 and IP all both show 1433 as the port, so I assume that means the server is using 1433.  My DBA has told me it's a named instance; what could I do to confirm that?  Thanks for the help!